# shell: how to know who is calling my script via ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, audit

Currently I have 3 ubuntu machines:

server1: perform as a server, it has a script called provider.sh

server2: client, it will call provider.sh in server1

server3: client, it will call provider.sh in server1

server2 and server3 both can ssh to server1.

They will get results at their localhost by calling `ssh <client_name>@<server1_ip> /path/to/provider.sh args1 arg2`

Well, for some concerns, **server1** wants to record **who** and **when** is calling its script provider.sh.

Is it possible to implement it by using shell without installing any other audit log tools?

Comment: well logins already get logged. see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/logging-ssh-access-attempts.

Comment: @avigil But it wouldn't record who is calling which script. right?

Comment: No but you would get logs like `Accepted publickey for <user> from <ip>`. If a server only calls one script you can infer from that when something is run. If you are doing something more complicated than you should probably not be doing your [RPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) via `ssh`